# Apache: (non)trivial rewrite of subdomains

Tags: apache, subdomain, url-rewriting

I have an (at least for me) non trivial task with a project running on an Apache2 VHost.

Assuming that I own the domain 'foobar.com' and created a 'wildcard catch all' for all subdmains at my registrars config panel I'd like to achive the following:

Every request going to 'api.foobar.com' should pass.
Every request going to '*.foobar.com' where * is everything but api should be rewritten to 'foobar.com'

It seems I am not able to write the correct rewrite condition and rule. Can anyone help?

Thx and regards.

Felix

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this.

```
RewiteEngine ON

RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} !^api\.foobar\.com$
RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} !^foobar\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/foobar\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Here you are *redirecting* any url with host other than `api.foobar.com` OR `foobar.com` to `foobar.com`

The above entries append the URL, if it is not desired you can skip the `$1` in the `RewriteRule` directive

*Updtae*
GeorgieF (OP) suggested the following regex and it shoul also work:

```
RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} !^(api\.)?foobar\.com$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/foobar\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hey danishgoel, thx but this does not work. I had to change the rule to: RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\foobar\.com\/$1" [R=301,L] but now I have infinite redirects that keep the pages from loading. And api.foobar.com is also redirected to foobar.com.

Comment: try adding the [OR} flag, I have updated my answer have a look at it

Comment: Both problems still there. api redirects, and then infinite redirects occur. Tried it with curl to exclude the browser as cause of an error. I think it should be one condition with a regex that says: subdomain must be empty or api. Something like !^(api\.)?foobar.com$

Comment: Its strange I have similar syntax in my own htaccess file and it works fine. I use my domain and its ip address and redirect everything else. But your regex should also work.

Comment: I have updated my answer have a look, also try my old regex that I have updated.

Comment: Both attempts do not work in my case. A problem may be my reverse proxy before the server itself. But even on the proxy that rules do not work as expected. Giving it up for now.

Comment: @GeorgieF Sorry that nothing worked for you, strange though as its working on my server. Well its best to give it a rest for now. Sometimes in a couple of days the solution presents itself. Good luck,